# Android and Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an Android app which is using Google Maps. Now, everything works perfectly on emulator, but when I deploy the app on my phone (temporarily just sending myself the apk file via g-mail), the app just crashes when it comes to the maps part. All I get is the "sorry" message.

I'm developing on Google API 7 and my phone (Samsung Spica) has Google Maps installed (and working). How can I find out what's causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have all required permissions for the application?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from your logcat. You can get that either via Eclipse, select Window->Show View->Other->Android - Logcat or via opening the ddms application inside the ANDROID_SDK/tools/ddms folder.

Comment: @evilone: I have these 3 permissions: INTERNET, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. If everything is working fine, my source should be ok? My problems are caused by the phone...

Comment: @alextsc: everything works fine on the Emulator (so, there's no problem in Eclipse).

Comment: Maybe this is a bit misleading or i dont understand it. What do you mean with the "sorry" message. "Sorry, Force Close"? If this is the case, there is usually an exception inside androids log. This is called logcat, you can see it as i described it above. (and has nothing to do with eclipse except that you can view it there) Otherwise please post the exact error or describe it more.

Comment: it's not about eclipse, if the app is crashing there will be at least a hint about the cause. connect your device via usb and post the logcat output after a crash

Comment: @alextsc: yes, that's the "sorry" message :) This is what it get from just opening the map on the emulator (which works!). http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=104909&c=6704997

Comment: @iDroid: one of the problems is, I can't find my USB, so that's not an option.

Comment: Ok so we got one step forward. :) I'm afraid searching your usb cable is the easiest way to solve this, otherwise we have to guess into the blue. =/

Comment: Ok. My bad :S Found out I wasn't handling my errors enough as I should (with Try - Catch blocks). So, maps work fine, there's another problem somewhere. Sorry and thanks to all (I can't answer for 7 hours so I'm posting a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you able to connect the device to your development computer and debug on the device so you can see Log cat messages?

You have to set

```
<application android:debugable=”true”>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Afaik you don't need the debuggable flag to view the logcat. :)